# macOS Screen drawing on top of Keynote presentation mode

Tags: swift, nswindow, appkit, nsbezierpath

I have a Swift app for macOS that successfully draws on the desktop and other apps using a transparent view that is rendered on top:

```
self.view.window!.level = Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.maximumWindow))
```

and subclassed NSBezierPath.

**However** when I try to run the app on top of Keynote in presentation mode, the app displays, and keynote runs, but as soon as I interact with the app, Keynote disappears.  I believe its still in presentation mode, just minimised. Upshot is, I can't draw on top of keynote slides in presentation mode.

Does anyone know how can I keep my app running on top of Keynote?

Apps like DeskScribble manage to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: "as soon as I interact with the app, Keynote disappears to the background"  "how can I keep my app running on top of Keynote"  What you are saying doesn't add up.

Comment: Fair enough, I will try to be more clear.  When I interact with my app, Keynote *appears* to drop out of presentation mode, it disappears.  I believe its still in presentation mode, just minimised.   Upshot is, I can't draw on top of keynote slides in presentation mode. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect this clarification. - Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I just bought Deskscribble because it said it could do this, but....  I was hoping this post would have the answer!